# Shifting Letters in Console C++

Tags: c++, console-application

I am trying to shift the cout text from the console down by moving the console cursor back to the start and outputting '\n'. But when I attempt to nothing happens.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
cout << "Hello!\nThis is a test!" << endl;
SetConsoleCursorPostion(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {0, 0});
cout << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Is there anyway to move the text down?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, Please edit your code to correct typos.

second : `(0,0)` puts the cursor at the beginning not at bottom.
third: `cout` should be after `SetConsoleCursorPosition`.
Last : It is recommended to know the console window dimensions or use other functions to get it.

If you want something facilitates console operations for you as a long term solution check [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

I tested with the following code and it works perfect.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {5, 5});
cout << "Hello!" << endl;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {5, 8});
cout << "This is a test!" << endl;
cout << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that I wanted to move the text I already put onto the console down.

Answer (score 0):

The secondary argument of the `SetConsoleCursorPostion` is the a coordinate for the cursor, so you have to set it like this: `SetConsoleCursorPostion(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {0, 2});`

And by the way, your code does not compile (`#includes` ???, no namespace for `cout`, etc.)